# Problem with Robotium.clickOnMenuItem()

Tags: android, robotium

When I make this call to Robotium:

```
solo.clickOnMenuItem("Sync");
```

sometimes I get the famous error trace:

> 09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity test.com.activities.ListActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@461d4660 that was originally added here
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:253)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at test.com.activities.ListActivity$Sincronizacao.onPreExecute(ListActivity.java:272)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at test.com.activities.ListActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(ListActivity.java:224)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.app.Activity.onOptionsItemSelected(Activity.java:2313)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2201)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:740)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:538)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:142)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   09-19 22:27:23.647: ERROR/WindowManager(20662):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:355)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:200)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:268)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.app.Dialog.cancel(Dialog.java:951)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at test.com.activities.ListActivity$Sincronizacao.onPostExecute(ListActivity.java:331)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   09-19 22:27:24.209: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20662):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

But if I make the call natively like this (the menuitem is the third one):

```
mInstrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
mInstrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);
mInstrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT);
mInstrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

I don't get any errors no matter how many times I run the test. Why I'm getting that behaviour?

Comment: do you have a small test case to trigger the problem?